# Git "bad sha1 file" error

Tags: git, version-control

Hello I have the following error by git-fsck, which cannot be cleaned by git-gc even in --aggressive mode. What can I do next to fix this repository error?

```
$ git-fsck
bad sha1 file: .git/objects/55/tmp_obj_a07724
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a simple answer, sadly. But this might help:

[Recovering from repository corruption](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#recovering-from-repository-corruption) (from the Git's user manual).

Comment: This link is 404.

Answer (score 7):

Err... `tmp_obj_a07724` suspiciously looks like a leftover temporary
file :)

What happens if you simply move it away from the `.git` directory
(after a backup of the whole thing)?

Comment: I had a couple of zero-sized `.git/objects/??/tmp_obj_??????` files left after a `git gc --aggressive`. Just removing them did indeed get rid of this message, and the repository still seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

From `man git-fsck`:

```
Any corrupt objects you will have to find in backups or other archives
(i.e., you can just remove them and do an rsync with some other site in
the hopes that somebody else has the object you have corrupted).
```